# how to make button, textbox and other components to adjust size when the form is in fullscreen

Tags: c#

i'm currently doing my windows application. I already set my form into fullscreen, the problem is other components won't adjust its sizes. i hope someone can help me. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2aae.png)

Comment: Please read [Ask] page first.

Comment: This has four different language tags - which one are you using?

Comment: Removed the language tags. Now add the tag for the **one** language you use. But first learn [ask].

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Windows and C, you need to trap WM_SIZE messages in your window procedure

```
LRESULT CALLBACK winproc(HWND hwnd, UINT wm, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp)
{
      ...
    case WM_SIZE:
        int width = LOWORD(lp);
        int height = LOWORD(wp);
        break;
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, wm, wp, lp);
}
```

Using the width and height values obtained from the `lp` argument, you can use `MoveWindow` calls to rearrange your controls. For example, if your window contains just an edit control, you can resize it like this:

```
MoveWindow(hwndEdit, 0, 0, width, height, TRUE);
```

This will make the edit control take up the entire client area of the window whenever it is resized.